# Posting on facebook wall using Request

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

All day I'm trying to figure how to post on facebook wall of my own account using my own program. I followed tutorials on facebook developer pages, but that didn't helped. Currently I have this Request code:

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();params.putString("app", "http://samples.ogp.me/##############");

//      List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
//      permissions.add("publish_actions");
//      Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(getMainActivity(), permissions));
        Request request = new Request(
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            "me/appnamespace:test",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST
        );
        Response response = request.executeAndWait();
        Log.print("Response: " + response.toString());
```

All this does is produce following error:

```
Response: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

This gives next to none information of what is wrong. 200 error code seems to have something to do with permissions.

I found on [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/publish-open-graph-story/) page this text:

> Error:
>
> {   "error": {
>       "message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions", 
>       "type": "OAuthException", 
>       "code": 200   } }
>
> Reason:
>
> You haven't authorized the app to publish to your timeline. Click on
>   ''Get Access Token'' and click the ''Extended Permissions'' tab.
>   Select the publish_actions permission and run your test again.

For some reason I can't add publish_actions to extended permissions in Graph API Explorer, because there is no option for that! Only publish_streams. So I add that.
I get this error there:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10
  }
}
```

In my application permissions page on facebook I have added publish_actions on **User & Friend Permissions** and publish_stream on **Extended Permissions** (I am unable to add publish_actions there).

In the end, no matter what I do I can't get message posted in facebook timeline unless I use WebDialog, which isn't what I need.

I'm out of options on what might be wrong. Any ideas would be appreciated.